# Linq method - Return all Recipes that contain all Tags selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This query gets all the rows from the join table, TagRecipes (many-to-many), where the `TagId` is found in a list, `tagIdList`, and lastly just returns the Recipe. How can I make it so it only returns Recipes that have all the tags in the list, `tagIdList`?

Basically, it's filtering by 'or', but I want it to filter by 'and'. The recipe must contain ALL the tags, not just some.

```cs
var allRecipes = await _context.TagRecipes
    .Where(tr => tagIdList.Contains(tr.TagId))
    .Select(i => i.Recipe).Distinct()
    .ToListAsync();
```

e.g, tagIdList = {17, 20 ,21 }

**TagRecipes**

[image: Join table data]

So, it should only return Recipe with RecipeId = 2, even though RecipeID 4 contains TagId 17

**Classes**

```cs
public class Recipe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Ingredients { get; set; }

    public string Instructions { get; set; }

    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TagRecipe> TagRecipes { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StarRating> StarRatings { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Binder> Binders { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class TagRecipe
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public int RecipeId { get; set; }

    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
    
    public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: If tagIdList contains single item, tagIdList = {17}, Should it return both? Recipe 2 and 4.

Comment: Yes. It must return Recipes that contain these tags, otherwise it doesn't return them. It doesn't matter if the Recipe contains other TagIds in addition to those found in tagIdList.

Comment: `context.Recipes.Where(r => r.TagRecipes.Any()).Where(r => r.TagRecipes.All(tr => tagIdList.Contains(tr.TagId))).ToArrayAsync();`

Comment: @Fabio: I tested your solution, it returns too many records.

Answer (score 1):

1. group TagRecipes by RecipId, so each RecipId (Key) has its own tagIds.
2. loop on each group to check if it has all the tags in the provided tagIdList, and if it has them all, store this RecipId (Key), in my case i created list of int **RecipIds**.
3. get all the Recipes in the RecipIds list.

I hope this could be helpful

```
        List<int> RecipIds = new List<int>();
        int count = 0;

        var RecipGroup = _context.TagRecipes.GroupBy(tr => tr.RecipeId);

        foreach (var group in RecipGroup)
        {
            count = 0;

            foreach (var tr in group)
            {
                if (tagIdList.Contains(tr.TagId))
                {
                    count += 1;
                }
            }

            if (tagIdList.Length == count)
            {
                RecipIds.Add(group.Key);
            }
        }

        var allRecipes = _context.Recipes.Where(r => RecipIds.Contains(r.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: If I understood the question correctly (and I'm not sure I did), wouldn't a better way to do step #2 be to loop over `tagIdList` and check that they are all included in `group`. That way you wouldn't have to take the risk of duplicates. Also, if `tagIdList` is a set, you could use [`ISet<T>.IsSubsetOf(IEnumerable<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iset-1.issubsetof?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_ISet_1_IsSubsetOf_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following solution using **Linqkit** will be the simplest way to solve this, and without returning duplicates.

```
var tagIdList = new List<int> {1, 2};

var predicate = tagIdList.Aggregate(PredicateBuilder.New<Recipe>(), (pred, currentTagId) =>
    pred.And(recipe => recipe.TagRecipes.Any(x => x.TagId == currentTagId)));

var result = _context.Recipes.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

Generates this SQL:

```
      SELECT "r"."Id", "r"."Name"
      FROM "Recipes" AS "r"
      WHERE EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM "TagRecipes" AS "t"
          WHERE ("r"."Id" = "t"."RecipeId") AND ("t"."TagId" = @__currentTagId_0)) AND EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM "TagRecipes" AS "t0"
          WHERE ("r"."Id" = "t0"."RecipeId") AND ("t0"."TagId" = @__currentTagId_1))
```

Code is tested and verified using an asp.net Core 5 app.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, it's filtering by 'or', but I want it to filter by 'and'.
> The recipe must contain ALL the tags, not just some.
> So, it should only return Recipe with RecipeId = 2, even though RecipeID 4 contains
> TagId 17

Since you want to filter the data by `and`, after filtering the data based on the tag, if group the result based on the `RecipeId` property, the item count in the group should be the equally with the tag list count. So, you could use the following query statement:

```
var tagIdList = new List<int>() { 17, 20, 21 };

var allRecipes = _context.TagRecipes.Include(tr => tr.Recipe)
   .Where(tr => tagIdList.Contains(tr.TagId))
   .ToList()
   .GroupBy(tr=> tr.RecipeId)
   .Where(c => c.Count() == tagIdList.Count)
   .Select(i => new { RecipeId = i.Key, Count = i.Count(), Recipe = i.FirstOrDefault().Recipe })
   .ToList();
```

The result as below:

[image]